# Simplifying a set of linear equations using Scipy/Python

Tags: python, scipy

I have a very large and sparse set of linear equations such that in matrix format they are of the form [A][x]=[B]. Moreover:

[A] is a square matrix. All values in both [A] and [B] are signed integers of size 8 bits (-128 to +128). Each row in the matrix [A] consists of only half a dozen entries so the matrix is very sparse.

The objective is to convert/simplify this set of linear equations or problem to a form [A]'[x]=[B]' where:

1. [A]' has been tranformed into a matrix such that each column/row consists of a single entry, while all other entries are 0.
2. The solution space for the new system is same as the original one i.e. the set of solutions for both: [A][x]=[B] and [A]'[x]=[B]' is always the same.
3. Note that we are not solving the set of equations but just simplifying them.

We can do this manually, using Gaussian Elimination for small matrices.

I am hopeful this can be achieved easily using one of its inbuilt functions in Scipy or one of other python libraries. Can someone please help me with this?

P.S. I am very new to Scipy and struggling with this so if someone could break it down, i would be grateful.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the *reduced-row-echelon form* (rref) of the matrix [A B]. AFAIK, there's no available scipy method, but sympy offers [one](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixReductions.rref) and also supports sparse matrices.

Comment: @joni thank you. this is exactly what i was looking for. How large a matrix sympy can handle in case where they are sparse as i mentioned? scipi can handle tens of millions of rows. is sympy that scalable?